# WolframAlpha website calculator powers

Tags: wolfram-alpha-queries

Would be surprised if this hasn't asked before. Also, not sure if tag is correct.

With my graduation I lost access to the free university Mathematica. Today, I was too lazy to do a simple matrix calculation and entered it into the calculator on WolframAlpha (in standard Mathematica notation).

Zounds! It worked! Now I got cocky but yes, it understood Transpose and DiagonalMatrix and Whatnot too. Obvious followup: Can the website do almost anything that Mathematica can (modulo time/space constraints)? Even run a little proggie with loops?

`a[0]:=1;a[n_]:=a[n]+1;a[3];` surely was too much.